# Code not Compiling different PC Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an automation script that runs perfectly.
But when i have copied the script to my colleagues the following line of code doesnt compile and gives the following error.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(oq.findElement("_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_industryQB_selectedIndustryLabel"), "F461300 Computer Wholesaling"));
```

Error below

```
Error:(231, 13) java: no suitable method found for until(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition<org.openqa.selenium.WebElement>)
method org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(com.google.common.base.Predicate<org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver>) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition<org.openqa.selenium.WebElement> cannot be converted to com.google.common.base.Predicate<org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver>)
method org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<V>until(com.google.common.base.Function<? super org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver,V>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) V
    (argument mismatch; org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition<org.openqa.selenium.WebElement> cannot be converted to com.google.common.base.Function<? super org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver,V>))
```

Here are the steps that i did.
installed IDE (intellj Idea), added jdk to the project, added selenium jar to the project.
Copied and pasted the Java files over.

I have even tried just copying the whole project over and every single method was resolved except for this one.

The script still works perfectly on my machine. But not on the new machine.

Feel Free to ask me any questions if it is not clear.

I am out of ideas now.

Comment: What version of `selenium` are you using?

Comment: at first i downloaded the new Selenium version on the website which was 2.45.0 and i noticed i was using 2.44 so i just copied the selenium that was on my pc to the new pc. At first i thought the library might of caused the problem. But i dont think so.

Comment: See the documentation. `textToBePresentInElement ` is deprecated

Comment: Hi  I understand that the method textToBePresentInElement is deprecated. but it still does not explain why the method does not compile. I have used the New method which they suggested and there is still  the same error.

Comment: I Think that the Problem is the Until key word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) **`textToBePresentInElement`** is Deprecated. You probably using an older version where it's not deprecated and your co-worker using latest version of `Selenium`

Use `textToBePresentInElementLocated(By, String)` instead

**Edit**
And, I am not sure how

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(oq.findElement("_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_industryQB_selectedIndustryLabel"), "F461300 Computer Wholesaling"));
```

will compile. the parameters

```
ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(By , String)
```

expects are *`By` , `String`*. You are trying to pass `WebElement` instead of `By` selector. Additionally, `findElement()` does not accept `String` but some kind of `By` selector which seems wrong to me as well.

Correct implementation: `public static ExpectedCondition<java.lang.Boolean> textToBePresentInElement(By locator, java.lang.String text)`

Comment: Sorry about that. I forgot to add that oq is a class that i created.

Comment: oq.findelement is the following method  `public WebElement findElement(String webElementId) {
        return driver.findElement(By.id(webElementId));
    }`

Comment: @TheJAVANoob That still returns `WebElement`. Simply pass `By.id('some id')`

Comment: If you see in the Documentation I am using the method `static ExpectedCondition<java.lang.Boolean> textToBePresentInElement(WebElement element, java.lang.String text)
An expectation for checking if the given text is present in the specified element.`

Comment: @TheJAVANoob You are actually right and that overloading is not deprecated. So, that makes little more complicated

Comment: I would still suggest you to try `driver.findElement(By.id("some id"))` instead

Comment: If you look at the error it talks about java: no suitable method found for until. There is something wrong with the Wait.Until that is causing the problem.  identifying the elements are easy because there are several ways of doing it.

Comment: I also would like to see the `imports`

Comment: `import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;`

Comment: One of my colleagues have solved the problem. I forgot to add a Libs folder which is under the selenium root folder to the project.

Comment: Well, glad you figured it out!